# confirm page with form result in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, forms, post

hi i am making a form with a confirm page where I would like to display what was input from the form and give the user a chance to check it before sending it in.

I have successfully done this by saving the form elements in the session:

```
    $this->Session->write('Visitor.confirm', $this->data);
```

and get it by:

```
<? $fields = $this->Session->read('Visitor.confirm')?>
<?php echo $fields['Visitor']['v_firstname']; ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->hidden('v_firstname', array('value'=> $fields['Visitor']['v_firstname']));?>
```

....for each field. but i cannot get the fields to send as a new form? there must be a simpler way!

many thx

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not clear on what you're trying to do here.  "but I cannot get the fields to send as a new form" is the unclear part.  Are you just trying to have them see the stuff they entered, then click a "confirm" button?  I'll subscribe to this RSS so I see when you clarify to try to help.

Comment: yes exactly. the first page has a form. the second page (confirm page)  just displays the result of the form where a "confirm" button is shown and thus pressing it inserts the data into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Is the 'confirm' button a submit button within your form with all your hidden fields? Or do you have it as a good old fashioned link, and hoping that it submits your hidden form data?

Is there a reason why you would not grab the values out of the session on the page after confirmation, as opposed to resubmitting everything in a hidden form?

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to post the form again. When user clicks confirm, and a confirm() action is called, you just have to save what's in $this->Session->read('Visitor.confirm');